# Exact duplicate is closed as duplicate of another one which is not exact

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I know the title kind of long but couldn't think of anything.

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593080/opening-a-file-in-a-mode-in-python-2-7) question (lets name it as q1). It is exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248020/whats-the-difference-between-r-and-a-when-open-file-in-python) (q2) but that is also closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r) (q3). Now the thing is eventhough q3 answers the q1 in some broad way, it isn't the exact duplicate like q2.

Question is while flagging these type of questions, which one should be selected?

Comment: I'm the poster child for wanting questions to be exact duplicates, but I think all three of these questions are exact duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be some additional explanatory text with the "Close as Duplicate", along the lines of:

> This material has already been covered by an earlier question and answers on the same topic.

It's completely appropriate for a question to serve as a signpost to a more general Q&A that contains the answer... as long as the general one isn't book-length so that the answer is hard to find.